# Why does my find command seem to execute twice?

Tags: shell, find

I have this find command that I use to remove files that are older as 30 days from a specific directory.

```
DIR="/path/to/backups/"
find $DIR -type d -ctime +30 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

When I run this command it works but I get a always the following respond:

```
find: `/path/to/backups/subfolder': No such file or directory
```

See it seems to me as if the find command is run twice or does find do anything else with result afterwards?
Or where could that error message come from?

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui my question is a duplicate. What is the "sto best practice" for that? Deleting the question? Or keep it here if somebody might search for the same term?

Comment: Do as you wish (I don't think there is a best practice for this). To me, the title in this one has a good SEO, so it can be a good entry point to this piece of knowledge :)

Comment: I think I'll keep it here.